# Groovy And Groovy++,Are they different?

Tags: groovy, groovy++

i recently came to know that groovy++ have been released, what is the major difference is in Groovy and Groovy++?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### From the groovy++ page http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/

Groovy++ is statically typed extension of Groovy programming language. Additionally to all goodies of standard Groovy it adds a lot of functionality

- compile time checking of code
- as fast as Java performance of compiled code
- easy mixing of statically and dynamically typed code
- very powerful type inference
- tail recursion traits (interfaces with default implementation)
- extension methods (compile time categories)
- standard library of utilities for functional programming, concurrency and distributed computing (early prototype stage)

Comment: It should be mentioned that I believe Groovy++ development has ceased, and static checking is being implemented for Groovy 2 (currently in beta)

Comment: See also: [What happened to groovy++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010207/what-happend-to-groovy)

Answer (score 7):

There is a good article on what Groovy++ brings to Groovy [here](http://drdobbs.com/open-source/229500788). It includes benchmark results, so you can see the performance difference vs. Groovy and straight Java.

Answer (score 6):

Groovy++ is an extension to the core Groovy 1.x language. You drop the GroovyPP.jar file into the Groovy library directory, add @Typed in front of the package keyword in your code, then run your code just as you would in core Groovy. It infers the types, AND runs faster!