# What happend to groovy++?

Tags: groovy, programming-languages, jvm-languages, groovy++

I just stumbled upon groovy++ and found it quite interesting.

Unfortunately it seems that it's not further developed?

- According to github the last commit was over a year ago.
- The mailing list is totally inactive and the last message was back in april.
- There are no recent news about it.

Has the project moved and has another name now? Has it become obsolete because of improvements to groovy? Or is it just discontinued?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groovypp stopped being updated about a year ago, and should be considered discontinued afaik.

Static compilation is now being added to Groovy 2.0 (via the `@CompileStatic` and `@TypeChecked` annotations).

There's some description of [the new Groovy features here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/new-groovy-20), and a performance comparison (for what it's worth) [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-20-performance-compared)

Related SO questions:

- [What is the performance of Groovy 2.0 with static compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11344412/6509)

Comment: "`Static compilation is now being added to Groovy 2.0 (via the @CompileStatic and @TypeChecked`" -- The @TypeChecked annotation doesn't bring static compilation, only @CompileStatic does.