# Groovy vs Groovy++

Tags: groovy, groovy++

I just read some few articles about Groovy++ and seems to be a huge improvement of Groovy itself.

Does anyone know how to make use of Groovy++ in Grails and with IntelliJ? I can see the latest version of IntelliJ supports Groovy and Groovy++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010207/what-happend-to-groovy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Development of Groovy++ stopped a few years ago, and many of the interesting features it had were reimplemented in Groovy, including `@TypeChecked` and `@CompileStatic`.

Groovy is now a huge improvement over older versions. Each release gets faster and adds more features, and with static compilation we get near-Java performance with a far less ceremonious Java alternative.

Traits aren't really new at this point, they were added to v2.3 two years ago, but they're really getting popular and have added another big feature to the language. They're almost as powerful as AST transforms, but far easier to work with.

[Groovy in Action, 2nd edition](https://www.manning.com/books/groovy-in-action-second-edition) was published recently and it's huge, filling in a lot of documentation gaps. It's by far the most recent and most comprehensive Groovy reference.

Comment: You still can't make things private though can you? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1875